# How do I create a folder with an assigned value using php

Tags: php, mkdir

I’m running php code located in a folder named php.
I want to create a folder in a folder named downloads which is outside of the folder named php.

When I run the php code it does create a folder in the downloads folder, but it give it the $folder_name instead of the assigned value (d1234567890) for $folder_name.

I’m sure I am overlooking something very simple. Can someone please point this out to me. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//create folder name
$folder_name='d1234567890';
mkdir('../downloads/$folder_name');
?>
```

Comment: Variables do not get parsed inside single quotes. Use double quotes. It's outlined in the duplicate.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I knew it was something simple. It now works.